# Simple XML load file and extracting information from the XML result

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml

What I have here is an XML based API lookup. I am loading the URL that's xml for the most part, into `simple_xml_load_file()`.

Pasting the URL into the browser, gives the XML output.

You can try the lookup link [here](http://api.peoplesearchxml.com/SearchServicePublic.asmx/SearchXML?sSearchRequest=<search><searchType>PartnerPeopleSearchByPhoneACW</searchType><searchCriteria><phone>5128435436</phone></searchCriteria><identification><websiteKey>7</websiteKey><partnerID>XYZCalledYou.com</partnerID><partnerPassword>eshwarrocks</partnerPassword><ipAddress>127.0.0.1</ipAddress></identification><formatting><maxResults>5</maxResults></formatting></search>),

I am loading the exact same link with quotes into the `simplexml_load_file`.

Where I am stuck is the extracting part, I would like to extract State, Carrier, City, County and the Phone type from the XML result.

This is my code to extract the `State`

```
$state = $simpleXML->searchService->searchResult->dataset->phoneInfo->rateCenter['state'];
```

It fails for some reason I don't know why. Doing a `echo` of `$simpleXML` doesn't gives any output.

So I am failing either with loading the XML URL or extracting, which is now clear with loading the XML.

So I am pasting the entire code for you to take a look,

```
<?php

$phoneNumber = 5128435436;
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));

$simpleXML = 'http://api.peoplesearchxml.com/SearchServicePublic.asmx/SearchXML?sSearchRequest=<search><searchType>PartnerPeopleSearchByPhoneACW</searchType><    searchCriteria><phone>'.$phoneNumber.'</phone></searchCriteria><identification><websiteKey>7</websiteKey><partnerID>XYZCalledYou.com</partnerID><partnerPassword>eshwarrocks</    partnerPassword><ipAddress>127.0.0.1</ipAddress></identification><formatting><maxResults>5</maxResults></formatting></search>';    

$xml = file_get_contents($simpleXML, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$state = $simpleXML->searchService->searchResult->dataset->phoneInfo->rateCenter['state'];
$carrier = $simpleXML->searchResult->dataset->phoneSearch['company'];
$city = $simpleXML->searchResult->dataset->phoneSearch['city'];
$county = $simpleXML->searchResult->dataset->phoneSearch['county'];
$phoneType = $simpleXML->searchResult->dataset->phoneSearch['lineType'];

echo $simpleXML. '<br><br><br><br><br>';
echo 'Phone Number: '.$phoneNumber.'<br />';
echo 'State: '.$state.'<br />';
echo 'Carrier: '.$carrier.'<br />';
echo 'City: '.$city.'<br />';
echo 'County: '.$county.'<br />';
echo 'Phone Type: '.$phoneType.'<br />';

?>
```

Thank you for taking your time looking into this, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pointing out to the wrong objects:

```
$phoneNumber = 5128435436;
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));

$simpleXML = 'http://api.peoplesearchxml.com/SearchServicePublic.asmx/SearchXML?sSearchRequest=<search><searchType>PartnerPeopleSearchByPhoneACW</searchType><searchCriteria><phone>'.$phoneNumber.'</phone></searchCriteria><identification><websiteKey>7</websiteKey><partnerID>XYZCalledYou.com</partnerID><partnerPassword>eshwarrocks</partnerPassword><ipAddress>127.0.0.1</ipAddress></identification><formatting><maxResults>5</maxResults></formatting></search>';

$xml = file_get_contents($simpleXML, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$dataset = $xml->searchResult->dataset[0];

$state = (string) $dataset->phoneInfo->rateCenter->attributes()->state;
$carrier = (string) $dataset->phoneInfo->operatingCompany->attributes()->name;
$city = (string) $dataset->phoneInfo->operatingCompany->attributes()->city;
$country = (string) $dataset->phoneInfo->rateCenter->attributes()->country;
$phoneType = (string) $dataset->phoneInfo->attributes()->lineType;

echo "
    <strong>State:</strong>         $state <br/>
    <strong>Carrier:</strong>       $carrier <br/>
    <strong>City:</strong>          $city <br/>
    <strong>Country:</strong>       $country <br/>
    <strong>Phone Type:</strong>    $phoneType <br/>
";
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Pf0OCl)

Comment: Thanks @Ghost it works now... +1 and the correct answer given :) Much appreciated.